# "For which kind of conjunctions we need comma?"

Tags: conjunctions, commas

For which kind of conjunctions we need comma before or after them?

"I went to the baker, and then I went home."

"I can eat my cake now, or I can eat it later."

"I am listening to music, while reading a book."

Is the comma need in those sentences or not?

Comment: No, it isn't and in the last one it's at least questionable, if not altogether ungrammatical.

Comment: for which conjunctions we need comma?

Comment: Commas aren't governed by conjunctions, they're governed by logical relations within and between clauses, and in written record of spoken language, by pauses in the speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I went to the baker, and then I went home. **yes**
>
> I can eat my cake now, or I can eat it later. **yes**
>
> I am listening to music, while reading a book. **no**

The rule is that if you can split your sentence into two sentences (or "independent clauses"), then you need a comma before the conjunction. So for example you need a comma for this one:

> I went to the baker. I went home.

But you can't do that with this one, so you don't need a comma:

> I am listening to music. <s>Reading a book.</s>

Comment: This does not click with my experience. "I went to the baked and then I went home" looks pretty fine to me. Are you sure you **need** the comma?